# Präposition "vor" mit Akkusativ oder Dativ bezüglich statisch sein oder dynamisch?

Tags: preposition, dative, accusative

Gibt es einen Trick, wie man erschließen kann, ob die Präposition *vor* den Akkusativ oder Dativ verlangt?
Beispiel:

> Warum steht einen Lastwagen vor **dem** Eingang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Räumlich, statisch*: Dativ

> Der Lastwagen steht vor **dem** Eingang.

*Räumlich, dynamisch*: Akkusativ

> Der Lastwagen fährt vor **den** Eingang vor.

*Zeitlich*: Dativ

> Der Lastwagen stand dort vor **einem** Jahr.

Und sonst grundsätzlich Dativ.

Siehe auch [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/2Kasus.html?MenuId=Word733#Anchor-vor-6873).

Comment: vielen dank Em1! aber Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, was bedeutet den satz "Der Lastwagen fährt vor den Eingang vor" auf Englisch!

Comment: @Armin "The truck drove up to the entrance.", so it's the movement towards the entrance as oppposed to being there.

Comment: ! Now i understand completely. thank you.